# How to import package in a java project from another java project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build-dependencies

I m working in a project A (java)in IntelliJ IDEA , now I need functionality from another project B(java) .I want to import desired packages from project B into Project A. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use multiple modules within the same project. One module can depend on another, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html. Another way is to export project B as a jar and add it to the dependencies of the project A, but this way you will always need to update the jar manually when the code in B changes.

Comment: Also if both projects need to use the same class C, consider moving C into a third, common project. Depending on C in whichever project first needed C is not the right way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a build system like Gradle or Maven. That way, **anyone** who is able to check out your projects from version control will be able to build your projects, **even if they choose not to use IntelliJ**. (While either Gradle or Maven would work, I do not recommend using the Ant build system, because it does not support dependencies out of the box.)

You can either create a multi-module Gradle build, which is the easiest, or you can even publish a jar to a repository like Artifactory and then depend on a particular version of that jar in your second module.